# How to get Notification to admin Using Rest Api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dbsql

Need an notification when a registration is complete or a new user is created on user side.This notification is shown in admin side.This is a REACT project and the backend is provided through django REST Api.

I created a seperate db for notifications ,it is not working automatically when a registration is completed.